# PuTTY Option: Remote command = 'Top' / How to retain session after 'q' command?

Tags: ssh, putty

Example #1) 'Unmodified' PuTTY login to default directory >> Enter 'Top' Command >>> enter 'q' = You land back at the root (default) directory.

Example #2) Use the PuTTY settings option `remote command` = "Top" >> From the top enter 'q' = Instant logout (session closed)

Example #3) Same as #2 w/ 1 difference: PuTTY `remote command` = echo "Hello World!";  top;

^^^
re **#3**: I was thinking the brief pause to echo (for example) Hello World! would simulate Example #1 and after 'q' I would land back "Home", but the result was equal to #2 (session closed)

**Quick Summary**: This is one of those things which *"should be simple"*; How do I login straight to the 'top' and still have a session after 'q'?

...

..
EDIT: An amazingly fast flood of answers for this time of morning!

> logout: not login shell: use `exit'

Here is the exact code which is working best:

```
top; /bin/bash -il
```

I'm also testing Phil's code now, his is virtually the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSH executes the remote command by passing it to your configured shell to execute. If you open PuTTY with the the remote command `top`, then SSH will run the following:

```
$SHELL -c "top"
```

When run with the `-c` argument, the shell terminates once the command terminates, which causes your session to end.

To run top and then stay logged in, you can use the remote command `top; $SHELL -l`. This will run top and then start a login shell.

Comment: +1 for maintaining the existing shell. (rather than just assuming bash, like me)

Comment: Yours creates the type of session I'm used to, w/ a 'normal' logout vs. the message  "logout: not login shell: use `exit'"

Answer (score 0):

It's logging you out because you told putty to run one and only one command in your remote session, which is top.

You could make a file `~/bin/topsh`, which said

```
#!/bin/bash
top
exec bash
```

and use putty's "remote command" option to try running that; once you leave top, the session will be overwritten with a bash shell, and when you leave that, you should be automatically logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your remote command to

```
top; bash
```

Answer (score 0):

One the remote command exits, the shell it runs in will also close, which ends your session. If your last command is `top`, then existing that will always close your session.

Try `top; bash` as your command and you'll run a shell after `top` exits. The session will only then end once you've closed that bash session.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to look at top's batch mode. You can do something like `top -n1 -b` to get a snapshot of the system. I'm not aware of anyway to get top to stop clearing the screen on exit.

Comment: This isn't what the question is about.